# Three baskets with numbered balls

Tags: mathematics, optimization

[image]

Three baskets and some balls are given to you. You are supposed to put these balls into these baskets by writing some positive numbers on the balls. But:

- The numbers you are supposed to write on them have to be *positive integer number*,
- In each basket, the numbered balls have to be *distinct*. (That also means you can put the same number in different baskets actually.)
- The sum of the numbers on the balls in all baskets has to be *at most* $31$.
- You do not have to put balls in every basket.

> What is the maximum value of the multiplication of the numbers written on the balls?

Comment: The rule: "You may not put any ball in any basket" is confusing, can you clarify this?

Comment: To restate the problem: you are to maximize the product of a series of integers such that: (1) all integers are positive; (2) their sum is <= 31; (3) no integer may appear in the series more than 3 times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> To make the product of the ball values as large as possible one needs to split up the 'budget' of $31$ into as many pieces as possible greater than $1$. Why $> 1$? Because balls with $1$ on them contribute to the sum but don't increase the product. Why as many as possible? Because $2 \cdot N \ge 2 + N$ (for $N \ge 2$), i.e. the total product will increase more by an additional factor of $2$ than by one of the factors being increased by $2$.
>  **Edit:** With regard to ffao's comment, I should add that there is exactly 1 case where the maximum number of factors is *not* the optimum, namely $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 < 3 \cdot 3$. In the final solution one will see that further 'finetuning' by replacing three $2$s by two $3$s is not possible, because there are already three $3$s (one for each basket) used.
>  
>  So let's start with filling $2$s into each basket. The product is $8$ so far and the sum is $6$. Continuing with $3$s in each basket we have a product of $216$ and a sum of $15$. Next would be 3 $4$s, resulting in a product of $13824$ and a sum of $27$. But as the rest 'budget' to fill up to $31$ is just $4$, this can not be used to write another number on a ball. Instead one needs to use this to increase the existing numbers.
>  
>  This increase should be spread among as many numbers as possible because $\left( N_1 + 1 \right) \left( N_2 + 1 \right) > N_1 \left( N_2 + 2 \right)$ for $N_1$, $N_2 \ge 2$. So let's first promote two $4$s to $5$s. Then we have a rest budget of $2$ from which we can promote a $2$ to $4$.
>  
>  In total we then have in the baskets:
>  1. basket: $2, 3, 4, 5$
>  2. basket: $2, 3, 4, 5$
>  3. basket: $3$
>  Sum is exactly $31$ and product is $43200$.

Comment: "As many as possible" needs more justification. For example, 3*3 > 2*2*2.

Comment: @ffao Thank you for pointing that out. I have added this to my answer.

Comment: The sum of the baskets shown is 36. Did you mean:$$(1): 3, 4, 5\\(2): 2, 3, 5\\(3): 2, 3, 4$$ That matches your description and has the indicated sum and product.

Comment: @PaulSinclair You're right. One $5$ was too much.